# UTF conversion functions in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, data-conversion, utf

I'm looking for a collection of functions for performing UTF character conversion in C++11. It should include conversion to and from any of utf8, utf16, and utf32. A function for recognizing byte order marks would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: The functions listed here are maintained in a GitHub repo, [.hpp](https://github.com/coder0xff/Plange/blob/master/source/utilities/utf.hpp), [.cpp](https://github.com/coder0xff/Plange/blob/master/source/utilities/utf.cpp) and [tests](https://github.com/coder0xff/Plange/blob/master/source/utilities/utilities_test/utf.test.cpp). Some UTF-16 functions have been disable because they do not work correctly. The "banana" tests in the utf.test.cpp file demonstrate the problem.

Also included a "read_with_bom" function for recognizing byte order marks.

```
#if _MSC_VER == 1900 //work around for bug in MS Visual C++ 2015 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f40dcd8-c67f-4eba-9134-a19b9178e481/vs-2015-rc-linker-stdcodecvt-error?forum=vcgeneral

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int16_t>, int16_t> convert;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int16_t *>(s.data());
    return convert.to_bytes(p, p + s.size());
}

std::string to_utf8(const std::u32string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int32_t>, int32_t> convert;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t *>(s.data());
    return convert.to_bytes(p, p + s.size());
}

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int16_t>, int16_t> convert;
    auto asInt = convert.from_bytes(s);
    return std::u16string(reinterpret_cast<char16_t const *>(asInt.data()), asInt.length());
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int32_t>, int32_t> convert;
    auto asInt = convert.from_bytes(s);
    return std::u32string(reinterpret_cast<char32_t const *>(asInt.data()), asInt.length());
}

#else

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

std::string to_utf8(const std::u32string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.from_bytes(s);
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(s);
}

#endif

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::u32string &s)
{
    return to_utf16(to_utf8(s));
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::u16string &s) {
    return to_utf32(to_utf8(s));
}

std::u32string read_with_bom(std::istream & src)
{

    enum encoding {
        encoding_utf32be = 0,
        encoding_utf32le,
        encoding_utf16be,
        encoding_utf16le,
        encoding_utf8,
        encoding_ascii,
    };

    std::vector<std::string> boms = {
        std::string("\x00\x00\xFE\xFF", 4),
        std::string("\xFF\xFE\x00\x00", 4),
        std::string("\xFE\xFF", 2),
        std::string("\xFF\xFE", 2),
        std::string("\xEF\xBB\xBF", 3)
    };

    std::string buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(src)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    encoding enc = encoding_ascii;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boms.size(); ++i) {
        std::string testBom = boms[i];
        if (buffer.compare(0, testBom.length(), testBom) == 0) {
            enc = encoding(i);
            buffer = buffer.substr(testBom.length());
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (enc) {
    case encoding_utf32be:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 4 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 4");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 4;
        std::u32string temp = std::u32string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char32_t>(buffer[i * 4 + 3] << 0 | buffer[i * 4 + 2] << 8 | buffer[i * 4 + 1] << 16 | buffer[i * 4 + 0] << 24);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    case encoding_utf32le:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 4 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 4");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 4;
        std::u32string temp = std::u32string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char32_t>(buffer[i * 4 + 0] << 0 | buffer[i * 4 + 1] << 8 | buffer[i * 4 + 2] << 16 | buffer[i * 4 + 3] << 24);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    case encoding_utf16be:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 2");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 2;
        std::u16string temp = std::u16string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char16_t>(buffer[i * 2 + 1] << 0 | buffer[i * 2 + 0] << 8);
        }
        return to_utf32(temp);
    }
    case encoding_utf16le:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 2");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 2;
        std::u16string temp = std::u16string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char16_t>(buffer[i * 2 + 0] << 0 | buffer[i * 2 + 1] << 8);
        }
        return to_utf32(temp);
    }
    default:
        return to_utf32(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code review if everything works properly.

Comment: I came to stack overflow to ask this question, and found there was no answer. I think I've used the site correctly.

Comment: I'm not saying you've used stack overflow incorrectly; I think this is a good question to ask on code review.

Comment: Why does your UTF-16->UTF-8 use `uint16_t` instead of `char16_t`? Same goes for `char32_t` and UTF-32. Is that required somewhere?

Comment: I do not understand the #if _MSC_VER = 1900, what's the difference between the vs2015 with vs2013/vs2012/vs2010?

Comment: Nicol Bolas, alpha, I've added a comment to the first line of the code to explain this.

Comment: ``error C4996:  'std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t,1114111,0>': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from <Windows.h> instead. ...`` C++17 in 2019 might require an update to this answer.

Comment: This relies on functionality _deprecated in C++17_. See [P0618R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946335/deprecated-header-codecvt-replacement). I don't think this answer states that clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a little [utf_ranges](https://github.com/tcbrindle/utf_ranges) library for doing just this. It uses Range-V3 and C++14.

It has both views and actions (if you're familiar with Range-V3 terminology) for converting between any of the three main UTF encodings, can consume and generate byte order marks, and perform endian conversion based on a bom. For example, reading a file from unknown-endian UTF-16 into a UTF-8 `std::string`, converting any of the seven unicode line endings to `\n`, looks like this:

```
std::ifstream source{path, std::ios::binary};

std::string str = utf::istreambuf<char16_t>(source)
                   | utf::view::consume_bom
                   | utf::view::utf8
                   | utf::view::line_end_convert;
```

Comment: Pretty nice! Any possibility for conversion to a one-header & one-source version?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my UTF-8 code from Baby X
(https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyx)

```
static const unsigned int offsetsFromUTF8[6] = 
{
    0x00000000UL, 0x00003080UL, 0x000E2080UL,
    0x03C82080UL, 0xFA082080UL, 0x82082080UL
};

static const unsigned char trailingBytesForUTF8[256] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5
};

int bbx_isutf8z(const char *str)
{
  int len = 0;
  int pos = 0;
  int nb;
  int i;
  int ch;

  while(str[len])
    len++;
  while(pos < len && *str)
  {
    nb = bbx_utf8_skip(str);
    if(nb < 1 || nb > 4)
      return 0;
    if(pos + nb > len)
      return 0;
    for(i=1;i<nb;i++)
      if( (str[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80 )
        return 0;
    ch = bbx_utf8_getch(str);
    if(ch < 0x80)
    {
      if(nb != 1)
        return 0;
    }
    else if(ch < 0x8000)
    {
      if(nb != 2)
        return 0;
    }
    else if(ch < 0x10000)
    {
      if(nb != 3)
        return 0;
    }
    else if(ch < 0x110000)
    {
      if(nb != 4)
        return 0;
    }
    pos += nb;
    str += nb;    
  }

  return 1;
}

int bbx_utf8_skip(const char *utf8)
{
  return trailingBytesForUTF8[(unsigned char) *utf8] + 1;
}

int bbx_utf8_getch(const char *utf8)
{
    int ch;
    int nb;

    nb = trailingBytesForUTF8[(unsigned char)*utf8];
    ch = 0;
    switch (nb) 
    {
            /* these fall through deliberately */
        case 3: ch += (unsigned char)*utf8++; ch <<= 6;
        case 2: ch += (unsigned char)*utf8++; ch <<= 6;
        case 1: ch += (unsigned char)*utf8++; ch <<= 6;
        case 0: ch += (unsigned char)*utf8++;
    }
    ch -= offsetsFromUTF8[nb];

    return ch;
}

int bbx_utf8_putch(char *out, int ch)
{
  char *dest = out;
  if (ch < 0x80) 
  {
     *dest++ = (char)ch;
  }
  else if (ch < 0x800) 
  {
    *dest++ = (ch>>6) | 0xC0;
    *dest++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
  }
  else if (ch < 0x10000) 
  {
     *dest++ = (ch>>12) | 0xE0;
     *dest++ = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
     *dest++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
  }
  else if (ch < 0x110000) 
  {
     *dest++ = (ch>>18) | 0xF0;
     *dest++ = ((ch>>12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
     *dest++ = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
     *dest++ = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
  }
  else
    return 0;
  return dest - out;
}

int bbx_utf8_charwidth(int ch)
{
    if (ch < 0x80)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (ch < 0x800)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (ch < 0x10000)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (ch < 0x110000)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int bbx_utf8_Nchars(const char *utf8)
{
  int answer = 0;

  while(*utf8)
  {
    utf8 += bbx_utf8_skip(utf8);
    answer++;
  }

  return answer;
}
```