# Linux utf16 to utf8 on c++

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I have `std::string utf16` containing text in utf16. This string I get from third-party library.
For example `std::string utf16("\x04\x1f\x04\x40\x04\x38\x04\x32\x04\x35\x04\x42")`. This text is equal Russian word `Привет`. How can I convert utf16 to `std::string utf8` containing utf8? In this instance utf8 looks like `std::string utf8("\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82")`.

Comment: Look into utilizing 3rd party libraries. Qt can help. Also a post that might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688417/utf-conversion-functions-in-c11

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Integrating QT within a project just to provide utf16->utf8 conversion is, to put it lightly, extremely overkill.

Comment: Also, a word of warning about that linked question: `wstring_convert` has since been removed from the standard library, so the accepted answer is not really a good recommendation anymore.

Comment: This is one of those few topics where the "good" answer is a library recommendation IMO. My poisons of choice these days are [nemtrif/utfcpp](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp) for lightweight stuff, and [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) where true robustness is required.

Comment: I use c++17. I think I will use nemtrif/utfcpp. But is there such a possibility in c++17?

Comment: @German Not out of the box. You have to either provide your own conversion function or use a library.

Comment: i use `#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

const char *str = "\x04\x25\x0";

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.from_bytes(s);
}

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

int main(){

 std::string s(str);
 std::string new_str = to_utf8(to_utf16(s));
 std::cout << new_str;
 return 0;     
}` But I get source string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @German That's a question in of itself. You should post it as another question, containing that code, what it outputs and what you expect it to output.

Comment: But FYI, codecvt is already officially deprecated as of C++17.