# Does std::format() accept different string types for format and arguments?

Tags: c++, printf

With `printf` I can do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170#size-prefixes-for-printf-and-wprintf-format-type-specifiers)

```
wprintf(L"%hs", "abc");
```

where the `format` is wchar_t * but argument is char *. Is this doable with `std::format()`, or do I have to convert one to the other prior?

When I do

```
std::format(L"{:hs}", "abc");
```

I get compile error about type mismatch.

Comment: Are you trying to equate C++ with C?  Does it work when you cast your argument?

Comment: I'm converting an old log function into using std::format(), and found this problem. Of course if I convert type it works but I'd rather avoid it if possible. Also, since it's variadic, the log function doesn't even know argument types.

Comment: The `%hs` specifier is a non-standard extension to begin with. So I wouldn't assume that `std::format` offers any such functionality.

Comment: Understandable. I guess I'll keep my old code. Well, I think `%ls` is in the standard, yet `std::format("{}", L"abc")` is not available too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It cannot.

As per [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification), the format string matches [Python’s format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), which does not have any magic for directly dealing with different string types or encodings. (Python does everything behind the scenes with CESU-8, IIRC.)

This is one of those things where I wish the C++ Standard would just Do The Right Thing™, but as the C++ Standards Committee still hasn’t hashed out how they want to handle string encoding transformations (as of Jan 2022) we are stuck with a dumb `std::format`.

The ultimate goal, I think (and hope), is that `std::format` will one day accept different string types and transform them properly for you without having to change the `fmt` argument. For now, however, you must [perform the transform yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688417/utf-conversion-functions-in-c11).

Alas, ATM `std::format` will only accept like string types for all arguments, where the base character type is either `char` or `wchar_t`. That’s it. ([More docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).)