# Is there an official TCHAR type in C++ now?

Tags: c++, c++11, character-encoding, tchar

If writing code which may be compiled with different character types, is `TCHAR` still the right type to use e.g `std::basic_stringstream<TCHAR>`

Or is there now some official C++/STL type which is preferred, in the way `wchar_t` replaces `WCHAR`, `true` replaces `TRUE` and `nullptr` replaces `NULL`?

I'm talking about cases where I'm using classes like `basic_string`, templated explicitly with TCHAR.

Comment: No. I consider wchar_t as nonsense (hence TCHAR, which is either char or wchar_t, is nonsense, too). Use utf8 if possible

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? Do you know in advance if what you want to stream is null-terminated? Variable-width? Fixed-width with embedded nulls?

Comment: @rubicks I'm not an expert on this stuff, does my edit clarify a bit?

Comment: No (It makes it worse)

Comment: `If writing code which may be compiled with different character types` Why? There is pretty mucn no reason anymore to write pre-unicode-compatible programs on Windows/Linux/Mac.

Comment: @deviantfan well you answered it yourself. I'm not writing a program. I'm maintaining one!

Comment: @Mr.Boy treat TCHAR as deprecated at best and harmful at worst. Also, consider delegating your unicode manipulations to libicu (http://site.icu-project.org/) or similar.

Comment: @rubicks thanks for the link, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11

Answer (score 8):

No. TCHAR allows you to switch between `char` and `wchar_t` based on Microsoft's _UNICODE macro and using Microsoft's various other 'T' macros. None of this is relevant to the standard C++ APIs.

If you're maintaining a legacy C++ program that uses TCHAR then you can just continue to use TCHAR.

For writing new programs what I've seen people prefer has been to avoid using legacy codepages entirely and instead use `char` as UTF-8, and then on Windows to use the *W APIs unconditionally, converting between UTF-8 `char` strings and `wchar_t` at the API boundary.

Comment: What does **"then on Windows to use the *W APIs unconditionally, converting between UTF-8 char strings and wchar_t at the API boundary."** mean?

Comment: @UnrealEngine5ComingSoon It means use the APIs ending in W directly, without the macros that switch between the W and A versions based on the UNICODE preprocessor definition. So instead of using the macro SetWindowText you use the function SetWindowTextW, and the text you want to set would be originally a `char` string using the UTF-8 encoding, which you convert to `wchar_t` immediately before you need to pass that text to the function. Windows has since begun supporting UTF-8 as the active code page, so you could instead ensure that's set, use the A functions, and directly pass UTF-8 data.

Comment: Thank  you very much.