# Error C2196: case value '?' already used

Tags: c++, c

Ok, curious error while building with Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (probably issue with ANSI, unicode etc) in the code...

```
switch (input[index])
{
    case 'א': // Alef Hebrew character
        if (/*conditional*/) 
        {
            // Do stuff.
        }
    break;

    case 'ב': // Beth Hebrew character
        if (/*conditional*/)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    break;

    default:
    {
            //Do some other stuff.
    }
    break;

}
```

The second case parameter generates...

```
Error C2196: case value '?' already used
```

Simple fix if possible.

Comment: There is no need of break after `default:`

Comment: What's the type of `input`?

Comment: Your compiler (which by the way is?) problably doesn't support  UNICODE sourc code.

Comment: If you save the file as utf-8 encoded then `א` is `0xD790` and `ב` is `0xD791`, so if `input[index]` is of type char both would try to match `0xD7`

Comment: Are you programming in C or are you programming in C++? Please choose one of the two.

Comment: Suspect OP is using a C++ compiler and not a C one.  Posting the name/version of the compiler would help.  Dual language tagging this post adds confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'א'` character cannot fit into a char. Usually it take several bytes, so `'א'` constitutes a "multicharacter literal", just like `'ab'`(NOTE: SINGLE quote is used).

A "multicharacter literal" has type int, and implementation-defined value. And, different multicharacter literal may have the same value, as there are infinite number of multicharacter literals.

In your case, apparently your compiler treated both `'א'` and `'ב'` as `'?'`, so it issues an error as the same value(`'?'`) appear after `case` labels twice in a same `switch`.

Assume you are using `wchar_t`, the fix is already given by Ivan.

If you are using `char`, then `א` is a multicharactar string instead of char. You can use function that compare strings to check whether `א` appears at a certain `index` of `input`:

```
const int ONE = 1;
if (strncmp(input+index, "א", sizeof("א") - ONE) == 0) {
      // Alef Hebrew character
    if (/*conditional*/) 
    {
       // Do stuff.
    }
} else if (strncmp(input+index, "ב", sizeof("ב") - ONE) == 0) {
     // Beth Hebrew character
    if (/*conditional*/)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
} else {
    // default:
    // Do 
}
```

Comment: I am not able to directly input `1`. It seems that without a English letter, part of the line would be changed to right-left instead of the normal left-right, and generates a wired output. So I used `ONE` instead.

Comment: The question does not state that the type of `input[index]` is `char`.

Comment: @barakmanos Right. But Alan already handle the whar_t part, which is mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `input` is an array of `wchar_t`s, your problem is that you're comparing a wide character to a narrow character literal.

As [PeterT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777689/petert) said in the comments:

> If you save the file as utf-8 encoded then `א` is `0xD790` and `ב` is `0xD791`, so if `input[index]` is of type char both would try to match `0xD7`.

That's why you're getting the error you mentioned.
(`char` has enough space to store an ASCII value, and the rest is omitted)

---

You can fix this by prefixing your literals with a capital `L` (turning them in to wide characters).

```
case L'א': // Alef Hebrew character
    if (/*conditional*/) 
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
break;

case L'ב': // Beth Hebrew character
    if (/*conditional*/)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
break;
```

---

Also, you need to make sure your source file is saved with unicode encoding & your compiler knows how to work with that.

Alternatively, you can simply escape the unicode value like so:

```
case L'\u05D0': // Aleph Hebrew character
// ...
case L'\u05D1': // Beth Hebrew character
```

Comment: The constants should be `\uD790` etc.  , it's an error to have `0x` there

Comment: It should be \u05D0 for Aleph and \u05D1 for Beth. D790 are utf8 encoded value, which is not what should be used after \u.

Comment: @IvanRubinson On Windows, `wchar_t` is a 16 bit type because Microsoft is shortsighted. Many Unicode characters have code points larger than that.

Comment: @FUZxxl on all compilers? Or just Visual Studio?

Comment: @IvanRubinson That's part of the Windows ABI, not compiler specific.

Comment: @IvanRubinson, does the same apply for Greek characters e.g. case L'β' || 'Β':
       if (/*conditional*/)
       {
        // Do stuff.
       } or case L'β' || L'Β':
       if (/*conditional*/)
       {
        // Do stuff.
       }

Comment: @loumbut5 No reason why not. Just try it and see.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Nope. Still get Error C2196: case value '1' already used in the second case case L'α' || L'Α': /*is fine*/ case L'β' || L'Β': /*C2196*/ Any ideas whats wrong? I'm building with visual studio ultimate 2012 and project properties is set to accept Multi-byte character set.

Comment: Try the second approach, the one with escaping (`'\u...'`)

Comment: case '\u03B2' || '\u0392': for case L'β' || L'Β': still generates C2196.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122751/discussion-between-loumbut5-and-ivan-rubinson).

Comment: This answer does not directly apply to C as `'א'` and `'ב'` are all ready distinct `int` values.  Still, using `L` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

C (and C++) are notoriously bad at unicode handling. The issue is that you're trying to fit some hebrew character into a `char`. But a char (a single byte) is only wide enough for ASCII.

If you're using modern (read, at least C++11) versions of C++, [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11).

If you're using C, you'll probably want to use [IBM's ICU](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/) library.

Comment: As C, code is not trying to "trying to fit some hebrew character into a `char`" as part of the `case`s.