# Output UTF-8 (u8) std::string

Tags: c++, utf-8, iostream

In C++11 and later, using the `u8` prefix on a string literal can create `char` (byte) sequences that are UTF-8 encoded.

How do you output those sequences to a `std::ostream`? How do you tell a `std::ostream` that a `const char *` or `std:string` to be output contains characters encoded in UTF-8, rather than the default encoding?

Comment: With a mixture of depression, bemusement, and anger, I am learning that [support for Unicode in standard C++ is terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106065/545127).

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The stream does not know or care what the encoding of the text is. Despite it's name, a `char` is not treated by `std:ostream` as containing a character encoded in the platform encoding. It must treats a `char` as a byte to be written out. It writes the "text" (byte sequence) as given (outside of possibly performing `\n` translation), assuming you don't imbue it with a facet that changes this. If you write characters that conform to UTF-8, then that's what ends up in the output.

Comment: Are you saying that a `std::ostream` treats a `std:string` as a sequence of bytes (one byte per `char`), rather than a sequence of characters in the platform encoding?

Comment: @Raedwald: Yes. It's just a sequence of `char`. What else would it treat the input as?