# clang std::isspace compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, clang++

Following code compiles fine on VS 2015(Update 3) and gcc 6.3 (C++14) without on any problems.

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::u16string ustr = u"Android";

    bool var = std::isspace(ustr[0],std::locale());

    return 0;
}
```

However, on [clang/Xcode](http://rextester.com/GZCZ93408) it fails with following error

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp:8:10: warning: unused variable 'var' [-Wunused-variable]
    bool var = std::isspace(ustr[0],std::locale());
         ^
In file included from source_file.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/locale:182:
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:705:44: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::ctype<char16_t>'
    return use_facet<ctype<_CharT> >(__loc).is(ctype_base::space, __c);
                                           ^
source_file.cpp:8:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::isspace<char16_t>' requested here
    bool var = std::isspace(ustr[0],std::locale());
                    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:427:53: note: template is declared here
template <class _CharT> class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY ctype;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:186:54: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::ctype<char16_t>'
    return static_cast<const _Facet&>(*__l.use_facet(_Facet::id));
                                                     ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:705:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char16_t> >' requested here
    return use_facet<ctype<_CharT> >(__loc).is(ctype_base::space, __c);
           ^
source_file.cpp:8:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::isspace<char16_t>' requested here
    bool var = std::isspace(ustr[0],std::locale());
                    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:427:53: note: template is declared here
template <class _CharT> class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY ctype;
                                                    ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

What am I missing here ?
Any header inclusion ? If so, which one is it ?
If not, any other workarounds to solve this ?

Comment: Defined in header <cctype> --> int isspace( int ch ), this function only  
 accepts one parameter

Comment: @FrankS101 OP is using the overload defined in `locale`.

Comment: I think the only "defined" solution would be to write one's own trait for it, since it's not already defined. Maybe a library defect, but it's debatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `std::locale` implementation of `std::isspace` uses character traits defined in [`std::ctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype), which define certain features of a character type.

Unfortunately the standard only requires that `std::ctype` is specialized for `char` and `wchar_t`, not `char16_t` like you need. It appears that MSVC and GCC are providing extra implementations (because it would make sense). (**EDIT**: GCC actually throws an exception).

We cannot add our own specialization for it because [namespace.std] states that we may only add specializations for user-defined types to `namespace std`.

This leaves us with a few options:

- Cast your characters to `char` or `wchar_t` before using `std::isspace` from `<locale>`

  - note that for `char` this will often be a *narrowing conversion* which you likely do not want
- switch to using the implementation of `std::isspace` from `<cctype>` which casts to an `int`.

  - if the type cannot be represented within an `unsigned char` you have undefined behavior, so this may also be not what you want depending on which type you use (check against `sizeof(unsigned char)`)
- write your own trait for your character type (probably the best choice right now)
- file a defect report, hope the committee agrees with you, and then wait for two years or more before it's fixed :-)

  - alternatively ask the clang writers to add this convenience (also not a bad idea)
- Write your own specialization like [`@Holt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281374/27678) did and just live with undefined behavior

---

Relevant: [How well is Unicode supported in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17103925/27678)

Answer (score 7):

The [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace) overload in `<locale>` is equivalent (per the standard) to:

```
std::use_facet< std::ctype<charT> >(loc).is(ctype_base::space, c)
```

As you can see, this requires a specialization of `std::ctype` for the given `CharT`.

The standard only provides `std::ctype<char>` and `std::ctype<wchar_t>`. Since `char16_t` is a built-in type, you cannot specialize `std::ctype<char16_t>` so I think you are screwed here.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is technically undefined behavior to provide a template specialization for a built-in type within the std namespace

Comment: @AndyG You're right, it's a flaw in the standard then, unless I'm missing something.