# Read a utf8 file to a std::string without BOM

Tags: c++11, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to read a utf8 content to char*, my file does not have any DOM, so the code is straight, (the file is [unicode punctuation](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf))

```
char* fileData = "\u2010\u2020";
```

I cannot see how a single unsigned char 0 > 255 can contain a character of value 0 > 65535 so I must be missing something.

```
...
std::ifstream fs8("../test_utf8.txt");
if (fs8.is_open()) 
{
  unsigned line_count = 1;
  std::string line;
  while ( getline(fs8, line)) 
  {
    std::cout << ++line_count << '\t' << line << L'\n';
  }
}
...
```

So how can I read a utf8 file into a char*, (or even a std::string)

Answer (score 0):

well, you ARE reading the file correctly into `std::string` and `std::string` do support UTF8, it's probably that your *console* *  which cannot show non-ASCII character.

basically, when a character code page is bigger than `CHAR_MAX/2`, you simply represent this character with *many* character. 
how and how many characters? this is what encoding is all about.
UTF32 for example, will show each character, ASCII and non ASCII as 4 characters. hence the "32" (each byte is 8 bit, 4*8 = 32).

without providing any auditional information on what OS you are using, we can't give a an advice on how your program can show the file's line.

*or more exactly, the *standard output* which will probably be implemented as console text.

Comment: I am not trying to output the code to console, but rather I am passing it to pcre, if I do it directly 'char* fileData = "\u2010\u2020";' then I can use '/p{P}' if I try to read the exact same data, the value is garbage and the regex no longer work.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2015, but I am using straight C++11, nothing 'window' specific.

Comment: the value is not garbage, it's utf8 encoded. you can google more about <regex> and utf8. read more about here, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254232/do-c11-regular-expressions-work-with-utf-8-strings

Comment: @SimonGoodman: You cannot assign a `"\u2010\u2020"` string literal to a `char*` like you have shown. You have to use `wchar_t*` instead: `wchar_t *filedata = L"\u2010\u2020";`.  In any case, if your PCRE library supports UTF-8 strings, you would simply read the UTF-8 data (UTF-8 is 8bit - hence its name - so can fit in `char` elements) from your file into `std::string`, just as you have shown. `getline()` will read the *raw* file data into `std::string`, and then you can use `std::string::c_str()` to pass the data to the PCRE library if it is expecting `char*` input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau theoretically speaking if the string literal is valid utf8 he can assign it to `const char*` with the `u8` prefix.

Comment: @SimonGoodman: FWIW, `"\u2010\u2020"` is `"‐†`, which is encoded in UTF-8 using `char` values as `"\xE2\x80\x90\xE2\x80\xA0"`.

Comment: But if I 'read' "\xE2\x80\x90\xE2\x80\xA0" from the file, then it is no surprise that the pcre does not find a match. Only a "\x2010" would be a match.
So I need to read into a wchar_t* and pass that to pcre, not a char*

Comment: PCRE can operate directly on the UTF-8 encoded string if you use the right flag. It is smart enough to figure out that those three bytes `"\xE2\x80\x90"` are one character.