# <regex> having trouble with Cyrillic characters

Tags: c++, regex, locale, regular-language, cyrillic

I'm trying to use the standard `<regex>` library to match some Cyrillic words:

```
  // This is a UTF-8 file.
  std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

  string s {"Каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан."};
  regex re {"[А-Яа-яЁё]+"};

  for (sregex_iterator it {s.begin(), s.end(), re}, end {}; it != end; it++) {
    cout << it->str() << "#";
  }
```

However, that doesn't seem work. The code above results in the following:

```
  Кажд�#й#о�#о�#ник#желае�#зна�#�#где#�#иди�#�#азан#
```

rather than the expected:

```
  Каждый#охотник#желает#знать#где#сидит#фазан
```

The code of the '�' symbol above is `\321`.

I've checked the regular expression I used with `grep` and it works as expected. My locale is `en_US.UTF-8`. Both GCC and Clang produce the same result.

Is there anything I'm missing? Is there a way to "tame" `<regex>` so it would work with Cyrillic characters?

Comment: i'm not so sure about it, but shouldn't you use `std::wstring` or `std::u32string` ,`std::wregex` or `boost::u32regex` and so on?

Comment: Are your strings utf-8 encoded?

Comment: @JohnDing You were absolutely correct. Using `wstring` et al did the trick. If you don't mind, I'll answer my own question shortly using this bit of knowledge.

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica Of course not, go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ranges like `А-Я` to work properly, you must use [`std::regex::collate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type#Constants)

> **Constants**
>   ...
>   collate    Character ranges of the form "[a-b]" will be locale sensitive.

Changing the regular expression to

```
std::regex re{"[А-Яа-яЁё]+", std::regex::collate};
```

gives the expected result.

---

Depending on the encoding of your source file, you might need to prefix the regular expression string with [`u8`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```
std::regex re{u8"[А-Яа-яЁё]+", std::regex::collate};
```

Comment: I can confirm this works and seems like a less intrusive solution compared to using wchars, surprised how few hits `regex::collate` has on Google!

Answer (score 1):

Cyrillic letters are represented as multibyte sequences in UTF-8. Therefore, one way of handling the problem is by using the "wide" version of `string` called `wstring`. Other functions and types working with wide characters need to be replaced with their "multibyte-conscious" version as well, generally this is done by prepending `w` to their name. This works:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

wstring s {L"Каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан."};
wregex re {L"[А-Яа-яЁё]+"};

for (wsregex_iterator it {s.begin(), s.end(), re}, end {}; it != end; it++) {
  wcout << it->str() << "#";
}
```

Output:

```
Каждый#охотник#желает#знать#где#сидит#фазан#
```

(Thanks @JohnDing for pitching this solution.)

---

An alternative solution is to use `regex::collate` to make regexes locale-sensitive with ordinary strings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60505502/161934) by @OlafDietsche for details. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) will shed some light on which solution might be more preferable in your circumstances. (Turns out in my case `collate` was a better idea!)

Comment: This post indicates that it might work with utf-8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254232/do-c11-regular-expressions-work-with-utf-8-strings?r=SearchResults